# How to run failed scenarios from jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, build-automation

in my project am using cucumber junit ANT.

am running 10 scenarios from jenkins, if some scenarios fails how to run only that scenarios again.

my test ruuner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
    features = "Feature Files"

    ,plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-json-report.json","html:target/html/"}
    ,glue={"com.mlc.testDefinitionLayer"}
    ,tags ={"@Tag1,@tag2,@tag3,@tag4"}  

  )

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

if not possible from Jenkins, at least can I read from excel sheet data like include/exclude inputs... and call java function(excel logic to read data) in test runner class and pick include(data in excel) test cases in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cucumber` offers a solution to rerun the failed `scenarios`.

It mentions it in the docs [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#rerun).

When you run `cucumber` you add a `rerun` formatter

```
cucumber -f rerun --out rerun.txt
```

This `rerun.txt` contains the failed `scenarios`. You can rerun them with:

```
cucumber @rerun.txt
```

In `Jenkins` this means adding another `build step` that will execute that command.